# gRPC service endpoint is not accessible via Kong Gateway

Tags: grpc, api-gateway, grpc-java, kong

gRPC services (developed in springboot) deployed as docker container on AWS linux (ec2). Started the docker image with port forwarding -p6565:6565. 
Now when directly hit via BloomRPC on laptop, it worked : ec2.IP:6565 Package.Service.Method

Configured service & route in Kong:

```
{
            "host": "ec2.IP",
            "created_at": 1588403433,
            "connect_timeout": 60000,
            "id": "e657d8df-6247-458a-a8e8-bec00c41e03c",
            "protocol": "grpc",
            "name": "aws-grpc1",
            "read_timeout": 60000,
            "port": 6565,
            "path": null,
            "updated_at": 1588403433,
            "retries": 5,
            "write_timeout": 60000,
            "tags": null,
            "client_certificate": null
}

Route:
{
            "strip_path": false,
            "path_handling": "v0",
            "updated_at": 1588403452,
            "destinations": null,
            "headers": null,
            "protocols": [
                "grpc",
                "grpcs"
            ],
            "created_at": 1588403452,
            "snis": null,
            "service": {
                "id": "e657d8df-6247-458a-a8e8-bec00c41e03c"
            },
            "name": "aws-grpc1-route1",
            "methods": null,
            "preserve_host": false,
            "regex_priority": 0,
            "paths": [
                "/grpc2"
            ],
            "sources": null,
            "id": "5739297e-3be7-4a0d-8afb-cfa8ed01cec2",
            "https_redirect_status_code": 426,
            "hosts": null,
            "tags": null
        }
```

Now hitting it via grpcurl -> its not working:

```
grpcurl -v -d "{}" -insecure ec2.ip:8443 package.service.pingMethod

Error invoking method "package.service.ping": target server does not expose service "package.service"
```

Here is kong config which looks related:

```
"proxy_listen": [
            "0.0.0.0:8000 reuseport backlog=16384",
            "0.0.0.0:8443 **http2** ssl reuseport backlog=16384"
        ],
```

So here are queries:
(1) can 8000 also be configured for https as insecure -> via passing a env KONG_PROXY_LISTEN variable at time of kong-container start by

```
    -e "KONG_PROXY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8000 http2, 0.0.0.0:8443 http2 ssl"
```

Is this good to do?

(2) How to enable server side reflection? OR what is use of /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expose **HTTP2 Proxy Listener** for Kong.
You can refer to this one: https://konghq.com/blog/manage-grpc-services-kong/

In short, you need to add env variable details for `KONG_PROXY_LISTEN` like so:

```
-e "KONG_PROXY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8000 http2, 0.0.0.0:8443 http2 ssl, 0.0.0.0:9080 http2, 0.0.0.0:9081 http2 ssl"
```

**Note:** apparently Kong uses the ports 9080 for HTTP2 and 9081 for HTTP2 SSL. But I think this can be changed.

And also expose those 9080 and 9081 ports like so, this is example for `docker run` command:

```
-p 127.0.0.1:9080:9080 \
-p 127.0.0.1:9081:9081
```

And use the 9080 port in `grpcurl` when you try to request, like so:

```
grpcurl -v -d '{"name": "Ken"}' -plaintext localhost:9080 facade.GreetingService/SayHello
```

Answer (score 1):

More updates:

gRPC deployed behind kong.ingress is working fine:

```
grpcurl -v -d "{\"greeting\":\"111\"}" -insecure acfb0xxxxx.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443 hello.HelloService.SayHello
```

Response:

```
Resolved method descriptor:
rpc SayHello ( .hello.HelloRequest ) returns ( .hello.HelloResponse );

Request metadata to send:
(empty)

Response headers received:
content-type: application/grpc
date: Sat, 02 May 2020 07:00:17 GMT
server: openresty
trailer: Grpc-Status
trailer: Grpc-Message
trailer: Grpc-Status-Details-Bin
via: kong/2.0.3
x-kong-proxy-latency: 1
x-kong-upstream-latency: 9

Response contents:
{
  "reply": "hello 111"
}

Response trailers received:
(empty)
Sent 1 request and received 1 response
```

when configured on kong-API-gateway, it is not working:

```
grpcurl -v -d "{\"greeting\":\"111\"}" -insecure kong.ce-gateway.ip:8443 hello.HelloService.SayHello
Error invoking method "hello.HelloService.SayHello": failed to query for service descriptor "hello.HelloService": rpc error: code = Internal desc = An invalid response was received from the upstream server
```

Comment: Is there any single good tutorial for gRPC service deployment and expose via kong-gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Http2 is now enabled by default for Kong, but if you are having issues, a good place to start is to inspect the `proxy_listeners` section of the global config. In my case, I found that http2 was only enabled for the SSL port, and not for the non SSL. A good way to see the global config is to send a GET request to the root url of the admin api, for example `GET http://localhost:8001/`.